# How to create an ObjC function outside a class in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to Obj-C and to Xcode. I have been surfing different tutorials for a few days now but there is one question I can't get straight:

I want to write a function to generate a dictionary from a long string before parsing the information to the rest of my iOS app. I imagine a small function on the side would do and I don't see how to justify defining a class with .h and .m files.

If I want to write a small function in Obj-C (and not C) in Xcode outside of a class, how do I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: is it like external method?

Comment: @Suhail Yea, like in Python I would just write function.py and just import it into whatever class I want to use it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from just creating a C function somewhere, you could also add a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) to `NSString`, which would probably be more in keeping with the Objective-C philosophy. That would make it possible to perform the operation on any `NSString` in your program.

Note, however, that the overhead is pretty much the same as creating a class, although that should not deter you from using this approach.

Comment: I agree with this. Adding Category to NSString or NSDictionary is better.

Answer (score 3):

Use plain C methods, for example:

```
// .h file
NSNumber *sum(NSNumber *x, NSNumber *y);

// .m file
NSNumber *sum(NSNumber *x, NSNumber *y) {
    return @(x.intValue + y.intValue);
}
```

Comment: Your code contains mistakes. Please rename NSInteger to NSNumber.

Comment: My bad. I knew something was amiss while writing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Objective C does not have functions, it only has methods.
If you want to write function use plain C.